# What do class_type='Main' and self.main = parent mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class x_Plugin(SpyderPluginWidget): 

    """Spyder plugin for unit testing."""
    # focus_changed = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent, class_type='Main'):
        """ 

        """
        SpyderPluginWidget.__init__(self, parent)


        self.class_type = class_type 

        self.main = parent #
```

What do `class_type='Main'` and `self.main = parent` mean?

Comment: I would strongly recommend a basic Python tutorial: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Those are assignments to instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

self.main = parent # principal is a main function of the program that is the same as the parent (parent with all its properties).